# Ignore expired tokens on certain routes

Tags: c#, api, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

Using JWT tokens, I was working on authentication for my .NET Core API. I was wondering if I can tell my API to ignore the expiry of my token when the user requests a certain route, like "/refresh" for example, to refresh expired tokens. I understand it can be worked around by supplying the tokens through a POST request, but I want the ability to ignore the expiry of a token when I only want to identify the calling user.

My code is done as below. Currently it works with a POST request but I want the ability to supply expired tokens through the header.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("refresh")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Refresh(RefreshRequest refreshRequest)
{
    // Validate refresh token
    if (!_tokenService.RefreshTokenValid(refreshRequest.Refresh_Token)) {
        return BadRequest("The request token is not a valid token.");
    }

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    // Validate actual token
    if (!tokenHandler.CanReadToken(refreshRequest.Token)) {
        return BadRequest("The JWT token is not a valid token.");
    }

    // Get the user from the JWT token
    var userId = _tokenService.GetUserIdFromtoken(refreshRequest.Token);
    var repoUser = await _repo.GetUserById(userId);

    // Map the user, generate a token and send response
    var newToken = _tokenService.GenerateRefreshedJwtToken(repoUser);
    var tokenUser = _mapper.Map(repoUser, new AuthRefreshedTokenUser(newToken));
    return Ok(tokenUser);
}
```

Comment: AllowAnonymous will skip the authentication middleware no matter you supply correct token or not  , what is the problem with current codes ?

Comment: AllowAnonymous completely ignores tokens. This means that the ClaimsPrincipal user will not be identified, and everything must be done manually. It's a possible solution, but not a better solution to manually getting tokens than what I have right now.

Comment: You can create another authentication schema and set not to validate token's lifetime  see below reply

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to create another authentication schema and set not to validate token's lifetime :

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    ...
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = false;
    ....

});
```

And apply that authentication scheme using  `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "schemeName")]` on specific controllers/actions.